# Dropdown (select option) not getting data - Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular11, angular-ngselect

Here is my model.ts

```
export interface IUserEducationalBackground {
    id: number;
    user_id: number;
    studies_type: string;
    year: number;
    course: string;
}
```

I have a dropdown like this.

```
<div class="col-5">
  <ng-select bindLabel="name" bindValue="name" [items]="studiesType" [(ngModel)]="studiesType.name"
  (Change)="searchStudies(studiesType.name)">
  </ng-select>
</div>
```

whenever this value is change i want to change html table data

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of educationalDetails; let i = index">
  <td>
    {{ item.year }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ item.course }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ item.awards }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Here's is my array i want to compare to api data

```
studiesType: any = [
    { name: 'Basic' },
    { name: 'Secondary' },
    { name: 'Undergraduate' },
    { name: 'Graduate' },
  ];
```

**UPDATE** 
This is my method to find user studies

```
public searchStudies(name: any) {
    let obj = this.educationalData.filter(m => m.Name == name);
    console.log(this.educationalData)
    this.educationalDetails = obj;
    console.log(this.educationalDetails)
  }
```

This is my api call.

```
private getUserEducationalBackground(user): void {
    this.apiService.getUserProfile('users/educational-background', user.id)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.educationalData = data;
        });
  }
```

When i console.log it gives the value of `console.log(this.educationalData)` but after that `console.log(this.educationalDetails)` gives blank array.
[image]

Comment: Typo error? `(change)` instead of `(Change)`.

Comment: Oh damn. Yes you're correct. Now i get the console.log but the table doesn't change its values.

Comment: Did you uncomment the code in `searchStudies` function? After that, did it work?

Comment: Yes then i console.log(this.educationalDetails) it gives me blank array.

Comment: Then it looks like something is wrong when you filter data from `educationalData`. What's the value in `educationalData`? Please share the data in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Yes sorry about that. I have updated the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246727/discussion-between-yong-shun-and-kael).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 1:** Consider using another variable for storing selected `studiesType`.

HTML

```
<ng-select bindLabel="name" bindValue="name" [items]="studiesType" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedStudiesType"
    (change)="searchStudies(selectedStudiesType)">
</ng-select>
```

TS

```
selectedStudiesType: string;
```

---

Issue 2: There are few errors in the filtering logic.

1. Missing `Name` property. Instead, use `studies_type`.
2. Compare both strings with ignoring case sensitive.

```js
public searchStudies(name: any) {
  let obj = this.educationalData.filter(
    (m) => m.studies_type == name.toLowerCase()
  );

  this.educationalDetails = obj;
}
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-raiof8?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: And thanks to Post Owner in the discussion for the debugging.